# Polygon color overlay

Tags: java, polygon, bufferedimage, graphics2d

If I draw a new polygon on the buffered image, the color between the polygon and the background should overlay, like on the picture below. Currently my code looks like this.

```
Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
graphics.setColor(triangle.getColor());
graphics.fillPolygon(polygon);
graphics.drawPolygon(polygon);
```

[image: Overlay Polygons]

Comment: Set the translucency of the color

Comment: Or use a `AlphaComposite`